# Thinkpad X1 Yoga 4th Gen 20QF intel graphics incompatible with insider preview build 20170+

Tags: windows-10, windows-insider

Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU

I've been struggling with an extremely frustrating intel graphics issue since upgrading from build 20161. All versions of the intel integrated graphics driver result in a gray screen/unusable display on insider preview builds 20170+.

The only "workaround" I've found to fix this is to plug in an hdmi to my tv which automatically switches the windows+p project/display options from "pc screen only" to "duplicate" finally enabling both my laptop and the tv display to work perfectly again (with the intel driver still installed). I then uninstall and delete the driver software for the intel driver and am stuck with the microsoft basic display adapter which works once the hdmi is unplugged, but unfortunately disables all of the intel graphics features including night light, brightness control, and hdr among others.

*Lenovo's latest driver (incompatible) (n2hdr29w.exe; 27.20.100.8187):*
[Intel HD Graphics Driver for Windows 10 (Version 1709 or later) - ThinkPad X1 Yoga 4th Gen, X1 Carbon 7th Gen - US](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x1-yoga-4th-gen-type-20qf-20qg/20qf/20qfcto1ww/pf1s6hsz/downloads/DS540184)

*Latest DCH driver direct from intel is incompatible as well (igfx_win10_100.8581.exe; 27.20.100.8581):*
[Download Intel(R) Graphics - BETA Windows(R) 10 DCH Drivers](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29786/Intel-Graphics-BETA-Windows-10-DCH-Drivers?product=80939)

Finally, Intel® Driver & Support Assistant (Intel® DSA) also fails to install a compatible driver and you guessed it, results in the same bug as well.

I've been trying to fix this for 2 weeks now. Any help, workarounds (i.e. allowing the intel driver to install w/o the gray screen), or similar experiences would be extremely helpful. Thanks.

note:
I tried reaching out to intel live chat support and they said all intel graphics drivers are incompatible with windows builds beyond 20H1 which is technically stated on the driver page, however I think it just means the driver is untested past 20H1 because everything worked fine as I said until I updated from build 20161.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  The behavior you describe indicates the driver is indeed not compatible with 20H1 Insider Preview builds.  You will have to wait for Intel to release an update that is compatible.  Just because it works on a previous build, doesn't mean the changes to the WDDM in the new build, didn't break compatibility.

Comment: I have a ThinkPad machine here (not yours)  with an older Intel GPU and it is running 2004 Insider build 20180.  This was a very large upgrade (and I was warned). Try upgrading yet again to see if that helps.

Comment: @Ramhound
I though one can't revert back to NON-preview builds once they've upgraded to a preview build without a clean install. I'm stuck on this build, so I'm looking for a workaround without a clean install or constantly having to leave the hdmi plugged in. I thought about trying a manual install via the .inf file in the latest driver zip from intel, but I doubt this would help.

Comment: If you go to Windows Insider (Update settings) on this machine and remove the machine from the Insider program, it may go back to the production version.

Comment: @John Thanks, I'll consider that as a last resort. I kind of like being in the insider dev channel though to see all the new features and this is the first time anything like this with graphics incompatibilities has occurred since I joined.

Comment: @cbeaman - You can't;  You will have to wait for an update to the Intel drivers that have been updated to support 21H1 (which is what 20180 is for not 2004)

Comment: @John - The author will be unable to go back to the production version until the first half of next year due to the build they are on.  **20180 is an Insider Preview build for 21H1 not 2004 despite the version that is reported.**

Comment: If you look at About (at least on my machine) it says V2004 Build 20180.  21H1 is just another name / synonym. That is the state of the nation here.

Comment: @Ramhound, Thank you. I'll just wait for the next update released by Lenovo and leave driver updates blocked in windows update.

Comment: @John - I have said this before.  Microsoft has not updated it yet. Microsoft themselves have indicated that the Development channel is currently will become 21H1 and the Beta channel is 20H2.  The version nomenclature has been discontinued, the next version will be "Month 2020 Update" and but also known as 20H2.  Likewise, 21H1 will be Month 2021 Update".